# Why does the JVM claim my PNG does not exist?

Tags: java, swing, embedded-resource

I am trying to set the upper-left image on a JFrame. However, it claims my PNG file is nonexistant. I set the icon with

```
mainFrame.setIconImage(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("C:/Users/Steve/Programming/Projects/Java/BibleReader/bibleReader/src/test/resources/assets/bible/textures/icon.png")).getImage());
```

This is the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at
javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source) at
com.nickson.input.UI.prepareGUI(UI.java:42) at
com.nickson.input.UI.<init>(UI.java:33) at
com.nickson.main.Engine.main(Engine.java:19)
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is this happening?

You are trying to open a resource with a path in the file system.  Resource paths should be relative to a directory or JAR file on the application classpath.

So in your particular case, the classloader is looking for a resource folder called "C:" relative to the resource location of current class.  Naturally, it doesn't exist.  And since `getResource` returns `null` if it cannot find a resource, this leads to an NPE.

Here are a couple of pages with detailed explanation of how resource loading and resource path resolution actually works:

- [Java resource loading explained](http://www.thinkplexx.com/learn/howto/java/system/java-resource-loading-explained-absolute-and-relative-names-difference-between-classloader-and-class-resource-loading).
- [Accessing Resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html) (Oracle)

---

As a guess, and assuming that you are using Maven, I think that the path `"/assets/bible/textures/icon.png"` would work if your code is running in a unit test.  For production code, I think you have the resource in the wrong tree; it should be in the `.../main/resources/` tree.